# Request admin role for facebook page using Graph API

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

How do I request for admin role of a facebook page, I only have the facebook page url and page id?

Just like in google docs, when a link is clicked and user doesn't have rights to view or edit that doc. It shows a button to request access.

I want to provide same kind of functionality for my users using facebook API.

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not possible; that functionality does not exist.

You have to contact one of the page admins and have them add you as an admin in the page settings – manually. There is not API for that.